# Image overlapping on border in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

This has stumped us.  I think it was the first time that we ever did an image container with a border-radius: 50% and the image inside resizes in scale when you rollover. We managed to keep the image in the container but the image still overlaps the border of the container.  Please see the [link](http://codepen.io/oninross/pen/KdKdrE) for reference.

```
a {
    display: block;
    height: 160px;
    width: 160px;    
}
.image-wrapper {  
    border: 6px solid red;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
}

a:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.25);
    transform: scale(1.25);
}

img {
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

**Note**: we cannot assign the border on the a tag as it will contain other things other than the image itself.

Comment: Which version of Safari?

Comment: I would like to say the latest one out there.

Comment: This happens only during transition on my machine, indicating that it's about a change in rendering… hm.

Comment: Would your setup allow for a background-image? One could simpy animate `background-size` instead of `scale` then.

Comment: @Paracetamol, I've seen that solution in the net.  Just throwing this in the wild just in case someone already has done a solution other than using background image.  I dont want to set a height to the wrapper as it will be dynamic and responsive